# PowerShell Reverse Shell

Tags: shell, powershell, reverse

Is there a way we can create a TCP or UDP server and a client in PowerShell and connect from the client to the server and giving command line access from the client to the server like a reverse shell.

It is easy to do it in Python but is there a way to do it in PowerShell.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. This is ahrdly an on topic question, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also [read asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). About your question, see `Get-Command *-PsSession` or `Get-Command New-PsSession Show`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell Remoting and create custom endpoint (to restrict user access to given subset of powershell commands). To get more details please read about commands related to PSSession and PSSessionConfiguration

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/31/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/